# Adding different opacities to 'active' and 'non-active' figure class

Tags: html, css, class, figure

I'm trying to create different opacities on images on a carousel slider.

There are two DIV classes for the one in focus and the rest which is out of focus/not active.

1. `figure class="flkty-carousel__cell gallery-item object-fit-img object-fit-img--loaded"`
2. `figure class="flkty-carousel__cell gallery-item object-fit-img object-fit-img--loaded is-selected"`

I want the loaded DIV to have opacity 0.5 and the 'is-selected' DIV opacity 1.

I can easily add this to the CSS:

```
.flkty-carousel__cell {
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

But now all the images get opacity 0.5.

How do I add the correct CSS to seperate the two DIV classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.flkty-carousel__cell.is-selected {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

This selector will target an element that has both the `.flkty-carousel__cell` class and the `.is-selected` class.

Comment: Wow, that was quick and easy! I learned something.

Thanks so much. Thumbs up!

Comment: Glad to have helped. If my answer solves your problem then please consider accepting it as the best answer.

Comment: Is there also a way to create a black background for only the non selected (inactive) image? The image now shows with a 0.5 opacity on a white background, but how can I make that background black?

Comment: You can apply any styles you want inside that selector. `background-color`, whatever.

Comment: I added a simple 'background-color:#000;' but nothing happening. Have to dig a bit deeper I guess. Thank you!

Comment: There might be a child element that has a background color on it, which you would override like so: `.flkty-carousel__cell.is-selected .my-child-element { ... }`

Comment: I had to add img at the end of the CSS classes.

This worked for me now:

`.flkty__cell, .flkty-carousel__cell {
    background-color: #000;
}`

`.flkty-carousel__cell img {
   opacity: 0.2;
   background-color: #000;
}`

`.flkty-carousel__cell.is-selected img {
    opacity: 1;
}`